# Making gmic run without verbosity in bash

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm writing some bash scripts, and I use gmic to generate some pictures. However, gmic prints the steps for each image. Is there a way to make gmic in "silent mode", that is, force it to run without being verbose ?

Comment: redirect the standard/error output to /dev/null

Comment: @IporSircer, It does not work. gmic remains verbose !

Comment: gmic do something > /dev/null 2>&1 works !

Comment: @IporSircer:  You might as well post your comment as an answer,  now that the OP has confirmed that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to redirect to STDOUT and then to `/dev/null`.

```
2>&1 gmic do_something >/dev/null;
```